# Apply function to multiple column of data.table

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, data.table

Is there any approach more efficient than lapply when apply function to multiple columns of data.table? It looks the lapply run each column one by one not parallelly. Hopefully there is better approach instead of using cluster package.

```
dt<-data.table(type=c(rep('H',500000),rep('L',500000)),a=rnorm(1000000),b=rnorm(1000000),c=rnorm(1000000))
setkey(dt,type)
system.time(dt<-dt[, lapply(.SD, function(.){rank(.)}), by = key(dt),.SDcols=2:4])
#user  system elapsed 
#1.41    0.05    1.45 

system.time(dt<-dt[, rank(a), by = key(dt)]) 
#user  system elapsed 
#0.41    0.00    0.41
```

The total time of running 3 column is almost almost equal to 3 times of 1 column.

Comment: *The total time of running 3 column is almost almost equal to 3 times of 1 column.* Do you expect it to get faster as more columns are added?

Comment: Generally the efficiency gains come more often from improving the inner portions of a loop. In this case, gross improvement is not likely, since rank's arguments get passed (eventually) to a C routine. Look at the code. If you wanted to bypass the setup steps that the outer R function wrapper to `.Internal(.Internal(rank(xx, 
        length(xx), ties.method))`, you might gain a few milliseconds.

Comment: Two questions: 1) "instead of using cluster package" - Do you mean you're not looking for a parallel solution or you'd like a better parallel solution (from your experience with cluster package)? 2) Are you looking specifically towards computing `rank()` or it was just an example to illustrate your question?

Comment: Thank you guys for the comments. I expect at least 20 times faster. If there is an efficient rank method, it might be helpful.

Comment: data.table v1.9.4 has a *non-exported* function called `frankv` that implements a much faster `rank`. You may want to have a look at it. It's scheduled to be exported in 1.9.8. The arguments at the moment are similar to base::rank (but that might change, for the better). The behaviour is identical, except when dealing with NAs/NaNs. base::rank doesn't consider NAs or NaNs identical , but data.table does. We might provide this (base's way of dealing with NAs) functionality as well in the future.

Comment: You can have a look [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/760) for some preliminary benchmarks (and some explanation).

Comment: Appreciate your help.